# For loop troubleshooting

Tags: python, for-loop

Hello everyone I am pretty new to programming and this is my first question on stack overflow.

Here I am writing a simple program that divides up a given amount of seconds into hours, minutes and seconds but I cannot seem to loop it as desired when I choose to insert more than 1 value.

Here is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def hms(s):
    seconds=[]
    for seconds in range(len(str(s))):
        h=seconds/3600
        m=(seconds - h*3600)/60
        s=seconds-(h*3600+m*60)

    return h, m, s
seconds = hms(10)
print seconds
```

Comment: People will know that it is a school assignment, believe me. Maybe it's better not to mention that explicitly.

Comment: I don't plan on copying anything I just want to understand where I am messing up...

Comment: I get the feeling you're trying to get by with doing as little work as possible, as opposed to taking your time and trying to understand what the heck you're doing: http://learnpythonthehardway.org

Comment: what the heck are you even trying to do? I don't even see what you need a loop for. someone was able to help you; but you need to make it clear what you are asking and what the requirements are.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, as stated this was my first question on this site and one of my first programs...so sorry if it looks ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the line `seconds = []` is completely redundant: you're simply creating a new variable that contains an empty list, and you're then immediately overriding that variable as soon as the for loop enters the first iteration.

Secondly, I'm not at all sure what the expression `range(len(str(s)))` is meant to mean: you're converting the number of seconds (e.g. `10`) to a string `"10"`, then taking the length of that string `2` and then iterating over the range `[0, 1]`. The loop variable `seconds` thus gets assigned the values `0` and `1` during the 2 iterations of the loop.

What gets computed as a result is in no way what you're trying to achieve. In fact, I'm not sure why you decided to use a loop at all for converting a single integer value to a single tuple.

In order to achieve what you want, you merely need to do a basic mathematical computation regardless of the programming language:

```
def hms(s):
    h = s / 3600
    s -= h * 3600
    m = s / 60
    s -= m * 60
    return (h, m, s)

print hms(10000)  # => (2, 46, 40)
print hms(1000)  # => (0, 16, 40)
```

If you need to work on a list of such values, simply define another function but do not complicate the basic logic:

```
def hms_list(amounts):
    ret = []
    for amount in amounts:
        ret.append(hms(amount))
    return ret

print hms_list([1000, 10000])  # => [(0, 16, 40), (2, 46, 40)]
```

the latter can also be reduced to a more compact form using a list comprehension:

```
def hms_list(amounts):
    return [hms(amount) for amount in amounts]
```

**Note:** On Python 3.x, the `/` operator will give you a `float` result, not a floored down integer, so in order for the above algorithm to work there, you need to use the integer division operator `//` which will also work on at least Python 2.7, e.g.:

```
h = s // 3600
```

Comment: Because it is requested that a list may be inserted into the function and return an output.
As for: 
range(len(str(s)))
I am trying to have the function iterate over a length l that goes from 0-nth number inserted in the function:
def hms()

Comment: Oh ok I see now! Thanks a million!